# Russel's paradox: what is the contradiction with $R \not\in R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, paradoxes

Let the Russel's Set be:

$$R = \{S | S \notin S\}$$ Where $S$ is a set

1. Suppose $R \in R$, but by definition $R \not\in R$, contradiction.
2. Suppose $R \not\in R$... (I am not sure what should be the contradiction here)

My guess: then $\{S | S \not\in S\} \not\in R$, then $R$ is not the set of all sets such that $S \not\in S$ OR $R$ is empty, but clearly it cannot be empty (?)

Can someone point out the contradiction in the second one?

Comment: Then by definition $R\in R$.

Comment: If $R\notin R$ then it satisfies the condition $S\notin S$ so $R\in \{S|S\notin S\} = R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $R\not \in R$. Then $R$ is a set that does not have itself as an element.

Since $R$ satisfies this condition, we conclude $R\in R$.... woops.